# Android Google Maps: Paint the entire map except for selected polygons

Tags: android, google-maps, colors

## My design

I am writing an Android app with a Google Map component. In this app, any user can perform specific map actions in certain regions. Therefore, I want to paint the entire map in grey - except for some permitted areas defined by Polygons.

[image]
**A Polygon - I would like to paint anything outside them.**

## Current code

The problem is that painting specific polygons is pretty straightforward with `.fillColor(Color.SOME-COLOR))`, so I can easily fill the polygons with color:

```java
FeatureCollection featureCollection = (FeatureCollection)geoJSON;
List<Feature> features = featureCollection.getFeatures();
for (Feature f : features)
{
    Polygon poly = (Polygon) f.getGeometry();
    <...>
    int c = Color.RED;
    com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon toAdd = 
        map.addPolygon(polygonOptions.strokeColor(c)
        .fillColor(Color.RED));
    toAdd.setGeodesic(true);
}
```

## How do I paint everything else?

How can I do the opposite - use `fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` and paint all the parts of the map that are not covered by a Polygon with a given color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create big polygon with hole in it:
according to doc:
A polygon can be convex or concave, it may span the 180 meridian and it can have holes that are not filled in.
Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html